# How to test React Native Slider

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, expo, react-native-testing-library

I have worked on a Slider component using [React Native Slider](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider). And now I want to test it by simulating the sliding gesture. But according to [React Native Testing Library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider) documentation, there are only three gestures which are:

1. fireEvent.Press
2. fireEvent.changeText
3. fireEvent.scroll

Is there anyway to simulate the sliding gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with react native library component testing, try out:

```
fireEvent(el, 'rowOpen', eventData);
// or
fireEvent(el, 'onRowOpen', eventData);
```

[Source](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/193)

This functionality can also be achieved with either Appium or Detox, and would require starting up a simulator or physical device. Both of them, under-the-hood would be using the Native Espresso/XCUITest drivers to achieve this.

I suggest using [Detox](https://toshev.medium.com/setting-up-detox-with-a-expo-managed-react-native-project-89342dce4df), or [Appium controlled via WebDriverIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/appium-service/).